# How to use TestCaseSource and TestOf attributes in the same test?

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm trying to define a [parameterized test](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Parameterized-Tests) that receives data using the [TestCaseSource](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) attribute. I also need to define an attribute to relate each test with a Jira ticket, and as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645207/jira-ticket-reference-in-nunit-header), I'm using the [TestOf](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestOf-Attribute) attribute as follows:

```
[TestOf("SomeId")]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SomeProviderClass), "someMethod")]
public void SampleTest(dynamic myData)
{
    //do something with myData
    //assert something
}
```

However, when excecuting the test, at TearDown, the size of TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties, that should have the TestOf value, is empty.
How should I define the attributes to be both properly recognized by NUnit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a TestCaseSource, you're actually creating a 'suite' of tests. NUnit test are structured in a tree. Normally, your assembly will be the top root of the tree, and each class within this a branch, which in turn branches to include all the individual test methods. i.e.

```
                           -Test1
              - TestClassA -Test2
                           -Test3
TestAssembly  
                           -Test4
              - TestClassB -Test5
                           -Test6
```

You can see this structure if you take a look at the TestResults.xml.

When you use `TestCaseSource` you're actually creating another level on the tree. So now your tree looks like this.

```
                                                -Test1A
                           -TestCaseSourceSuite -Test1B
                                                -Test1C
              - TestClassA -Test2
                           -Test3
TestAssembly  
                           -Test4
              - TestClassB -Test5
                           -Test6
```

In your example, `TestCaseSourceSuite` would be named `SampleTest`. The reason that what you currently have doesn't work, is that the `TestOf` attribute is currently applied to `TestCaseSourceSuite`, rather than `Test1A`, `Test1B` `Test1C`. (Properties like TestOf don't copy up or down the tree hierarchically.)

---

Anyway. How do we fix it?  Using TestCaseData for your TestCaseSource seems like the best bet. TestOfAttribute doesn't actually get a much use, so there isn't a 'named property' for setting the value, but you can use the `SetProperty` method and `PropertyNames` class instead. Try something a little like this...

```cs
public class MyTests
{
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataClass), "TestCases")]
    public void Test(int n, int d)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}

public class MyDataClass
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData(12, 3).SetProperty(PropertyNames.TestOf, "MethodUnderTest");
            yield return new TestCaseData(12, 2).SetProperty(PropertyNames.TestOf, "MethodUnderTest");
        }
    }  
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't know about the creation of another level on the tree when using  TestCaseSource. I tried the solution you propose, however, it might not be suitable in my case, given that sometimes the same TestCaseData is used for several tests, for I'm using the same "json body" as data for different API tests. For now, I'm using `TestExecutionContext.CurrentContext.CurrentTest.Properties.Set("JiraID", "SomeID");` inside the test to define the property. However, I'm not sure it's a good approach. Any other suggestions would be of help. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, that this isn't the best approach. This particular API was never intended to be exposed, so may disappear in future! See this issue for history there: https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/3136

Unfortunately there isn't yet a supported way to add test properties at runtime - that's what issue #3136 is about adding, but as you can see nobodies volunteered to take that on yet. For the time being, the only 'supported' way to do this is a test-creation time, as above. Could you parameterize your TestCaseSources in some way, to get around your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the background in this issue. After analyzing this with our team, we ended up creating a separate configuration file that has an entry for every test method, and matchs its name with the corresponding id that we where expected to use in Jira. That file is accessed at the end of each test to get the id. We opted for that given that we thought it will be more easy to mantain in time. It is similar to what you propose, that would be a great option if we werent reutilizing the test cases data. Thanks again for your help!